# How to deal with a column in a pandas dataframe, which has multiple datatypes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, lstm

I am working with a dataset for Activity Recognition, where they have monitored activities using sensors. In this, there is a column called "Sensor Status" which contains values of different datatypes. In case, of a motion sensor, the value in Sensor Status column is "On" or "Off", but in case of a Light Sensor, it has a numeric value such as 29.5 or 25 etc. I need to feed this dataset as input to a classifier but it obviously needs to be encoded first. How can I perform label encoding or one hot encoding on this dataset? Alternately, is there a way to create different columns for different sensors and then store their status values?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pandas Categorical data type:

```
# create a series (with mixed types and repeated values):
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['ON', 'OFF', 20.5, 21, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5])
s = pd.Categorical(s)
print(s)

[ON, OFF, 20.5, 21, 21.5, 21.5, 21.5]
Categories (5, object): [20.5, 21, 21.5, OFF, ON]
```

Use `s.codes` in the classifier (these will be consecutive integers):

```
s.codes

array([4, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int8)
```

Then, you can use `s.categories` to convert codes back to your original values:

```
s.categories

Index([20.5, 21, 21.5, 'OFF', 'ON'], dtype='object')
```